# How to troubleshoot layout switching when it "locks" on specific layout?

Tags: kde, keyboard-layout, xkb

Recently I installed ChakraOS based on Arch with KDE and I cannot switch layout. Neither graphically, nor from cli. The strange thing is that I can switch to spanish with various other distributions like (?)ubuntu, arch linux, fedora, mint, debian, sabayon, so it certainly isn't a hardware related problem.

Problem example:

1. I add Spanish layout (with the Spanish flag) setting a proper shortcut key.
2. Cannot change layout to Spanish, not even when I click the Spanish flag in the system tray icon.
3. I remove English, so the only layout is Spanish. Now, I ***can*** write in Spanish.
4. I add English (not switching yet) and then I can continue writing in Spanish.
5. I switch to English and then the English layout "locks" and cannot switch back to Spanish.

I have consulted this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78980/how-do-i-change-currently-selected-keyboard-layout-from-command-line%20and%20tried%20in%20vein:):

```
xkb-switch -n
xkblayout-state set +1
```

How should I find out what is the cause of this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Disabling fcitx (responsible for asian layouts) which is installed by default, lets kde handle the layouts normally. You can even uninstall it or disable it from starting on startup. You will see an icon at the system tray.